# ISO 8601 repeating internal of time only

Tags: iso8601

I'd like to represent a repeating interval of two time components in UTC, so for example:

1. Every day from 08:00 to 10:00.
2. Every day from 11:30 to 16:31.
3. Every day from 14:03 to 14:04.

Counting on [time representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times) and [intervals representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals):
Does `hh:mm/hh:mm` hold? So in my examples `08:00/10:00`, `11:30/16:31`, `14:03/14:03`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not giving a complete answer, but it seems that the ISO 8601-2:2019 extension has some answers for you (but I don't have it).

Some reviews tell of new "repeat rules for recurring time intervals".

And I found an early draft of the extension, which used the "FREQ=DA" (as frequency equals daily) expression, but I am not sure how to use this exactly.
According to a review sample of the file, it is explained in:

ISO 8601-2:2019

Sections:

13 Recurring time intervals with repeat rules

13.1 General

13.2 Method of specification

13.3 Specification of time interval

13.4 Repeat rule

13.5 Representations

13.6 Evaluation of a repeat rule

Comment: Thanks but I'm also not sure how to use it or whether it's relevant.